# BinaryReader overwhelming me by padding byte array

Tags: c#, .net

So I have this really simple code that reads a file and spits its data out in a hex viewer fashion. Here it is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace HexViewer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(new FileStream("C:\\dump.bin", FileMode.Open)); 
            for (int i = 0; i < br.BaseStream.Length; i+= 16)
            {
                Console.Write(i.ToString("x") + ": ");
                byte[] data = new byte[16];
                br.Read(data, i, 16);
                Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", " "));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that after the first iteration, when I do

```
br.Read(data, 16, 16);
```

The byte array is padded by 16 bytes, and then filled with data from 15th byte to 31st byte of the file. Because it can't fit 32 bytes into a 16 byte large array, it throws an exception. You can try this code with any file larger than 16 bytes. So, the question is, what is wrong with this code?

Comment: I'd say the `i` in `br.Read(data, i, 16)`. Shouldn't this be `0`?

Comment: I agree with @DeCaf. The index doesn't reference in the data to be read, but the index in the output array. In this case, the data should always be written to the start of the outputted array, thus the value should be 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `br.Read(data, i, 16);` to `br.Read(data, 0, 16);`

You are reading in a new block of data each time, so no need to use `i` for the `data` buffer.

Even better, change:

```
byte[] data = new byte[16];
br.Read(data, 0, 16);
```

To:

```
var data = br.ReadBytes(16);
```

Comment: I.. I can't believe it worked. But the index is from the beginning of the file and Read() doesn't use Stream.Position right? Right?

Comment: Read() *does* use its internal stream position, so you don't need to track it. You only need `i` to document the current position in your Console output, as you are doing.

Comment: The `index` parameter is the first index in the array you want to start reading into.